# Map of Tuple Enum Values to Enum Value in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, enums

I am working on some homework that requires me to evaluate python variable types pre-runtime in C++, sort of like a first pass of a compiler or something. Part of how I am trying to do it is make a map of tuples where each tuple contains an operator and two operand types, i.e. ("str","str",'+') that would map to the output type of str. To this effect I have made two enums: one of types, one of operands, and trying to implement that in code as such:

```cpp
enum PYTHON_TYPE{
    NUMBER=0,
    LIST=1,
    STRING=2,
    FUNCTION=3,
    UNDEFINED=-1
};

enum PYTHON_OP{
    PLUS='+',
    MINUS='-',
    MULT='*',
    DIV='/'
};

map<tuple<PYTHON_TYPE,PYTHON_TYPE, PYTHON_OP>,PYTHON_TYPE> operations;

PYTHON_TYPE python_operation_output_type(PYTHON_TYPE t1, PYTHON_TYPE t2, PYTHON_OP op){
    return operations[make_tuple(t1,t2,op)];
}
```

My problem stems where I try and put values into this map, where I do `operations[make_tuple(PYTHON_TYPE.NUMBER,PYTHON_TYPE.NUMBER,PYTHON_OP.PLUS)]=PYTHON_TYPE.NUMBER;`
This fails saying that "expected primary expression before . character" for the dots after `PYTHON_TYPE` and `PYTHON_OP`.

Comment: That's just not the syntax how you access enum values. BTW: Common coding guidelines mandate `ALL_UPPERCASE` for macros and only for macros.

Comment: You can do NUMBER or make it an enum class and do PYTHON_TYPE::NUMBER

Comment: If you don't show the code that fails to compile, then we can't tell what is wrong in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ uses the scope resolution operator (`::`), not `.`, to allow you to refer to enumerators.

This will work:

```
operations[make_tuple(PYTHON_TYPE::NUMBER, PYTHON_TYPE::NUMBER, PYTHON_OP::PLUS)]
    = PYTHON_TYPE::NUMBER;
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/AbRNe8)